# ASP.NET Core MVC, Azure Role based Authentication - Authorize Attribute failure - no Role claim returned?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, roles

I am to build an ASP.NET Core webapp with .NET6.
I have followed the Azure-Sample repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles/README.md)

I have adjusted the appsettings.json with AzureAd section:

```
 "AzureAd": {
        "ClientId": "my-client-guid",
        "TenantId": "my-tenant-guid",
        "Domain": "my-tenant-name",
        "ClientSecret": "my-client-secret-guid",
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "Scopes": "user.read,profile,openid",
        "ClientCapabilities": [ "cp1" ],
        "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
    }
```

- **ClientId** and **TenantId** fields are fed from [Azure Portal AD Application Blade](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade) , where I have created the App Registration. On
  the detail page of this application is the Overview blade - which
  gives reference to ClientId, TenantId.
- **ClientSecret** has been created at the same page, at Certificates & secrets blade.
- **Domain** is provided from [Azure Domain list blade](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/DomainsListBlade)

User roles (Reader/Admin) have been created at the above (Azure AD Application) page.

Still on the same page:

- **Authentication Tab** a new **Web platform** was added with Redirect URI *https://localhost:7293/signin-oidc*. As for **Front-Channel logout** *https://localhost:44321/signout-oidc* was provided.
- **[ID Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens)** is ticked under **Implicit grant and hybrid flows** section
- **Single Tenant** option (only allow organization accounts)
- **Public flows** disabled

In [Enterprise Applications](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/StartboardApplicationsMenuBlade/%7E/AppAppsPreview) my application is listed. In the details view of the application:

- **Properties tab**: Assignment required is set to false. I do not want to preassign users to the app
- **Visible to users**: set to false
- **Users and groups** tab: the Security groups have been created for which the Roles (Reader/Admin) are assigned to. Members are assigned to Security groups. For testing purposes I have added my Azure AD User as well with Reader role.
- **Single Sign-On**: Here I see the following message: *The single sign-on configuration is not available for this application in the Enterprise applications experience. {{my-application-name}} was created using the App registrations experience*
- Sign-in logs: oddly enough I see here my logins, so I assume that the role claims are not transferred to my WebApplication, since I get Unauthorized error upon opening the view at the controller.

**The WebApp references**

Config sections I have mapped to a model so I can inject if needed as IOptions
**MicrosoftGraphConfiguration** to map GraphApiUrl:

```
public class MicrosoftGraphConfiguration
{
    public const string ConfigurationName = "MicrosoftGraph";
    public string? GraphApiUrl { get; set; }
}
```

**AzureAdConfiguration** to map AzureAd configurations

```
public class AzureAdConfiguration
{
    public const string ConfigurationName = "AzureAd";
    public string? ClientId { get; set; }
    public string? TenantId { get; set; }
    public string? ClientSecret { get; set; }
    public string? Domain { get; set; }
    public string? Instance { get; set; }
    public string? BaseUrl { get; set; }
    public string[]? ClientCapabilities { get; set; }
    public string[]? Scopes { get; set; }
    public string? CallbackPath { get; set; }
}
```

**Program.cs** to add configure and add services to the DI container, etc.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.Configure<MicrosoftGraphConfiguration>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(MicrosoftGraphConfiguration.ConfigurationName));
builder.Services.Configure<AzureAdConfiguration>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(AzureAdConfiguration.ConfigurationName));

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration, subscribeToOpenIdConnectMiddlewareDiagnosticsEvents: true)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "User.Read" })
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AssignmentToReaderRoleRequired", policy => policy.RequireRole("Reader"));
    options.AddPolicy("AssignmentToAdminRoleRequired", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
});

builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();

    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Controller actions for testing purposes:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
{
    GetTenantDetailsResult tenantDetails = new();
    
    if (this.tenantService != null)
    {
        tenantDetails = await this.tenantService.GetTenantDetailsAsync();
    }

    return View(new TenantViewModel(tenantDetails));
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("/Reader")]
[Authorize(Policy = AuthorizationPolicies.AssignmentToReaderRoleRequired)]
public IActionResult Reader()
{
    var asd = User;
    return Ok("He is a reader");
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("/Admin")]
[Authorize(Policy = AuthorizationPolicies.AssignmentToAdminRoleRequired)]
public IActionResult Admin()
{
    return Ok("He is an admin");
}
```

Launching the app (without cookies - incognito) redirects me to
[https://login.microsoft.com/{my-tenantId}/oauth2/authorize?...](https://login.microsoft.com/%7Bmy-tenantId%7D/oauth2/authorize?...). Once logged in, endpoints without the [Authorize(...)] attribute works well.

Opening any of the above endpoints (where [Authorize] attribute is in place) gives me HTTP 404 and redirects to:
https://localhost:7293/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2Freader

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#app-roles-vs-groups), the Roles Claim should be sent together with any ID Tokens.
"*These assigned app roles are included with any token that's issued for your application, either ... or ID tokens when your app is signing in a user*"

I am unsure -thus my questions are- if:

- The roles claim are not sent?
- The roles claim are sent but cannot be parsed
- How to proceed with the debugging to find out the issue

As a weird behavior.. if I open the application/Reader endpoint in Incognito/InPrivate browser window, I get a HTTP 500 response code after the login with the following error details:
**MsalServiceException**: *A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details. You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details. Original exception: AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret provided. Ensure the secret being sent in the request is the client secret value, not the client secret ID, for a secret added to app*

Even though the ClientSecret is as above mentioned, I believe it is correct.
A reason for the Http 500 might be that currently I do not maintain an endpoint for https://localhost:7293/signin-oidc

I appreciate helps, as I am a bit lost here for 3rd day.

Thx

Comment: I have checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921391/asp-net-mvc-c-sharp-authorizeroles-not-working but I do not need a custom role provider. I do maintain roles in the Azure tenant

Comment: I have also checked the expiry of the generated client certificate. It is valid until late 2024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application named **WebApp-RolesClaims** and followed the same steps mentioned on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles/README.md)

I have adjusted the **`appsettings.json`** file with same **values** as you like below:

```json
 "AzureAd": {
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "Domain": "my-tenant-name",
        "TenantId": "my-tenant-guid",
        "ClientId": "my-client-guid",
        "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
        "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc",
        "Scopes": "user.read,profile,openid",
         // To call an API
        "ClientSecret": "my-client-secret-guid"        
    }
```

[image]

Now I ran the sample, and it took me to **Microsoft login** page.

When I signed in with Azure AD user credentials, I got **consent screen** like below:

[image]

After accepting the above consent, it gave me **same exception** as you like below:

[image]

As the error message says, it usually occurs if you include **`Client secret ID`** instead of **Client secret value**.

To **resolve** the error, you need replace `"ClientSecret"`  with below:

[image]

**Note** that, key value will be visible only for **few seconds** after secret's creation and you cannot retrieve it later.

If that's the case, delete the existing secret and create **new secret** to copy it's **`value`** like below:

[image]

I have adjusted the **`appsettings.json`** file by replacing Client **Secret value** as below:

[image]

When I ran the sample now, I got the **claims** of signed in user including **`roles`** like below:

[image]

So, try changing **Client Secret** with *key value* in your **`appsettings.json`** file .

Comment: thank you! Indeed it was the main issue and it also turned out that the domain name was incorrect (we have multiple registered alteregos). I had to change from mydomain.com to  mydomain.onmicrosoft.com to make it work.